# Looking for a python/java text editor for MacOSX

Tags: macos, text-editor

Is this the right place for this Question?

May someone please recommend a text editor like notepad++ for Mac. I trolled through the net and cant seem to find anything close or anything that's free.

I have been using Notepad++ for a while but have recently made an enviornment change to OSX to understand and learn more about other platforms.

Comment: It would be helpful it you mention for which language you intend to use it for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want free, you can download XCode from Apple for free.  It's quite a power IDE, so if you're only after a text editor, it may be too much.

Comment: Is there to turn off the project building prompts, when starting a new file?

Comment: I haven't played with it outside the scope of an Apple-specific projects.  Have a look at preferences and also at project information - there may be some options there

Answer (score 0):

I use TextMate. There's a 30 day trial if you just want to check it out. It's not free but you get what you pay for.

http://macromates.com/

Comment: @Brent hmmm $53 is a lot to spend on a TE.. I like the look of it, will test it out.

Comment: $53 is a lot to spend but for my use nothing else comes close... I thought the same thing, tried the trial and by the end there was no way I would switch to something else. @brent haha, great minds think alike.

Answer (score 0):

Try TextMate http://macromates.com/

lol Jeff you beat me by 15 seconds